# using my oauth provider behind a reverse proxy

Tags: oauth, jersey, reverse-proxy

I try to use my OAuth provider developed with Jersey behind a apache reverse-proxy

the client uses POST https://api.com/resource/oauth/request-token
my oauth provider receives POST http://api.com/**mywebservice**/resource/oauth/request-token

the signature cannot be verified so the request fails

have you any idea about resolving this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oauth provider behind reverse proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142278/oauth-provider-behind-reverse-proxy)

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating a ContainerRequestFilter that gets executed before the OAuthServerFilter. The ContainerRequestFilter can re-set the URI on the request (by calling setUris() method) to what it should be to pass the signature verification (if that info can be made available to you somehow - e.g. in some custom header).

Comment: exactly what I have done but I didn't have the time to give the answer here. thank you